# Issue with background processes (alsa, pulseaudio)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

When I try to run `mpg123` or `arecord` in background mode from command-line (e.g. `mpg123 a.mp3 &`) the programs block or give error:

mpg123:

```
mpg123 shot.mp3 &

High Performance MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 Audio Player for Layers 1, 2 and 3
        version 1.25.10; written and copyright by Michael Hipp and others
        free software (LGPL) without any warranty but with best wishes
(for ever...)
```

arecord:
usually, but not always says that the device is being used...

How can I fix it? Could anyone give me some references?
And, how to save with pulseaudio the same results?

Note: I have `alsa` and `pulseaudio`, but I am still a beginner user: they were installed a few months ago...

EDIT: Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @David Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS